# PDFTron not printing multiple copies

Tags: printing, pdftron

I'm trying to print multiple copies of a report via PDFTron, using the code:

```
Dim pdfDoc As New PDFDoc("C:\Test.pdf")
Dim pages As New PageSet(1, pdfDoc.GetPageCount)

Dim pm As New PrinterMode
pm.SetCollation(True)
pm.SetCopyCount(3)

PDF.Print.StartPrintJob(pdfDoc, "", pdfDoc.GetFileName, "", pages, pm)
```

But whenever it runs it only prints 1 copy.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Are you printing to a physical printer, or a virtual printer?

If a virtual printer, then typically a single file is created containing all the copies, so check the total page count to see if it is a multiple of the source (assuming you are not printing multiple pages to a single paper).

Otherwise, the destination printer might not support multiple copies, though I doubt that is the case. You could verify by printing from another application (such as wordpad) to the same printer and see if you can print multiple copies or not.